# Is there a way to open .csv in R skipping the first X rows, where X is variable based on where specified headers can be found?

Tags: r, read.csv

I am trying to read a number of .csv files within a folder and combine all of the data into one data frame for analysis and graphing.  Generally, I would use this approach in order to load and combine all of the files.

```
    file_list <- list.files(paste(WorkingDirectory, "/Transducer Data", sep= ""), pattern = "*.csv", 
    full.names = TRUE)

    for (file in file_list){
       all_transducer_file <- read.csv(file, header = F, as.is = T, sep= ",", skip = 15) 
     }
```

However, I am encountering a couple of issues.

1. The .csv that are generated have differing number of rows before the data.  The headers for the data appear to always be: "Date and Time", "Seconds", "Pressure (PSI)", and "Surface Water Level (ft)". The number of rows varies based on how many errors were thrown by the device since the last data pull.
2. The data is sometimes loaded as "chr" type and sometimes as "factor" type. I don't really understand the difference between those or how that might affect the coding.

Is there a way to open csv skipping the first X rows, where X is based on where specified headers can be found?

Comment: In your loop, first use `readLines(..., n=100)` so you can read in the first 100 lines (or whatever is the largest you would need to find the header). Then use `grep()` or something to find the index of the line that contains the header. Then use that as the `skip=` parameter to `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you know that `Date and Time` appears in the header try this:

```
library(data.table)
fread(filename, skip = "Date and Time")
```

See `?fread` for additional arguments which you may or may not need.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a work around to solve the problem in hand;

Problems and solutions:

1. Not knowing where skip starts -> using grep to get row at which column names start
2. Some columns become factor and some character -> using read_csv or set stringsAsFactors = FALSE in read.csv

#### Getting file names and skip rows

```
# Setting the file path which contains the csv data
file_list <- 
  list.files(paste(WorkingDirectory, "/Transducer Data", sep= ""), pattern = "*.csv", 
             full.names = TRUE)

# Here we get the line at which the table we want starts
# sapply is used to loop on each file we have
# grep("Date and Time", readr::read_lines(x))[1] -> reads lines of data and get row at which Date time exist
# We minus this row by one to use it as skip number
skip_lines <- 
  sapply(file_list, function(x){grep("Date and Time", readr::read_lines(x))[1] - 1}, 
         USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

#### Reading of the data

```
# Here I am using purrr to loop on data but you can use
# a normal loop or apply family, the benefit of map_df (function in purrr)
# is that it automatically returns data as a dataframe without needing to bind it
library(purrr)

# Method one using read.csv
1:length(file_list) %>% # I am looping on the files
  map_df(function(x){
    # For each file we read it skipping number of rows in skip_lines vector
    # stringsAsFactors = FALSE -> to avoid conversion of any column to factor (both character and factor will be character)
    read.csv(file_list[x], skip = skip_lines[x], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })

# Method two using read_csv
1:length(file_list) %>%
  map_df(function(x){
    readr::read_csv(file_list[x], skip = skip_lines[x], col_types = cols())
  })
```