# Read data file - array like structure - data starts after certain number of rows

Tags: r

I am trying to read in some txt files that look like this:

```
dat typ outc
16 4 0 0 0
W9001 W9002 W9003 W9004 W9005 W9006 W9007 W9008 W9009 W9010 W9011 W9012 W9013 W9014 W9015 W9016
*KDY       bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb
*K6P       aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
*RDY      bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb
*Rhh       aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
```

Any ideas what kind of data type is this or how to import it in R?

Comment: skip 2 rows, and read.table as usual: `read.table(someFile.txt, skip = 2)`

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59636239/680068 (can't find direct duplicate post, I will post my comment as an answer below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip 2 rows, then *read.table* as usual:

```
read.table("someFile.txt", skip = 2)
```

Or using *data.table::fread*, it is good at guessing where the data starts:

```
fread("someFile.txt")
```

or state how header starts, here I am assuming it starts with "W":

```
fread("someFile.txt", skip = "W")
```