# Read txt with space as separator AND in col names

Tags: r

This question is slightly related to my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017203/read-data-file-array-like-structure-data-starts-after-certain-number-of-rows?noredirect=1#comment118460602_67017203), but on a different topic.
My dataset in the txt has spaces as delimiter and in some col. names.
Is there a smart way to distinguish between the two?

So, in the following example, the name of the 1st col is "KDY A1" and the 2nd "K6P B3":

```
dat typ outc
16 4 0 0 0
W9001 W9002 W9003 W9004 W9005 W9006 W9007 W9008 W9009 W9010 W9011 W9012 W9013 W9014 W9015 W9016
*KDY A1       bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb
*K6P B3     aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
*RDY      bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb bb
*Rhh       aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa
```

I use  `fread("data.txt",header = FALSE,fill=TRUE ,skip = "W")` to read this, as suggested in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017203/read-data-file-array-like-structure-data-starts-after-certain-number-of-rows?noredirect=1#comment118460602_67017203), and the result is:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
W9001   W9002   W9003   W9004   W9005   W9006   W9007   W9008   W9009   W9010   W9011   W9012   W9013   W9014   W9015   W9016       
*KDY    A1  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb
*K6P    B3  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa
*RDY    bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  bb  
*Rhh    aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa  aa
```

Ideally, the "W90*" etc should be the row names and the KDY A1 etc, should be the col names.

Comment: Are the aa, bb all numeric? Is there a way of telling which are column names and which are column values?

Comment: Are you confusing rows and columns in your question? Because otherwise it doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas The aa will be numeric and bb will be in lower case. Good point!

Comment: @  Konrad Rudolph. In the end the data frame will be transposed.